# Calculating truncated cone taper angle from a projected image

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

[image]

I am imagining a truncated cone with taper angle $\phi$, shown in the left of the figure. I view the truncated cone inclined at some angle $\alpha$ from its axis. If $\alpha$ is large enough, I will see one of the circular faces and two line segments corresponding to the outside of the cone. These line segments will appear (in my 2D projection) to be separated by an angle $\theta$.

My question is this: how are $\phi$, $\alpha$, and $\theta$ related?

Apologies if I missed any relevant related questions.